# How to test SBT plugins

Tags: sbt

Is there any tutorial for the scripted plugin? Or maybe a new way to test plugins. I've found a [tutorial](http://eed3si9n.com/testing-sbt-plugins) that seems to be a bit old.

If I have to resort to Scripted, some questions that come to my mind:

1. Do I need to publish local my plugin before running scripted?
2. Can I refer to the version located in *version.sbt* from my tests?

For the record, I'm also using the [cross-build](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-cross-building) plugin, so if possible, the tests would need to cover both 0.12 and 0.13 versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Author of the linked [testing sbt plugins](http://eed3si9n.com/testing-sbt-plugins) here) There hasn't been major changes to `scripted` since I first wrote it, but I updated some of the details.

1. To test the plugin end-to-end, publishing locally I think makes sense.
2. See the updated post. You can pass version number as a property using `scriptedLaunchOpts`, and catch it with `System.getProperty` on the other side.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where is this page http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.7.7/docs/ChangeDetectionAndTesting.html in the new sbt documentation?

Comment: Well, I was able to do it. Scripted is still the recommended approach with SBT 0.13, and it works well. You can add a rule "scriptedRun <<= scriptedRun dependsOn publishLocal" that always publishes your plugin before running the tests. The cross-build version of scripted works well too. It just wasn't easy to understand the instructions.

Answer (score 3):

Eugene's answer is still relevant, but now, Sbt Plugins Testing has a proper documentation page in the official sbt documnetation site:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Testing-sbt-plugins.html